# What is the relationship between single and double source gamma radiation?

Tags: radioactivity

I am a physics student currently undertaking a labs project about gamma radiation, we measured the spectra of different sources using a scintillation counter, my lab partner and I were wondering if there is a specific relationship between the count rate for a single source and the count rate of two sources of the same element. Initially we considered that the count rate from source 1 would be added to the count rate from source 2 however from our results we can see that this isn't the case. If there are any resources you could point us towards it would be really helpful.

Comment: What's the geometry of the sources (e.g. point sources) and the measurement (distance to the detector)? How did you measure two sources (e.g. stacked on top of each other)? How strong are these sources; did you see the effects of detector dead time or coincidence summing?

Comment: Maybe dead time in your detector?